# Callback in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm studying about callbacks and other stuff like this, and in this

book(https://javascript.info/callbacks) there was example with this code

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.onload = () => callback(script);
  document.head.append(script);
}
loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.2.0/lodash.js', script => {
  alert(`Cool, the script ${script.src} is loaded`);
  alert( _ ); // function declared in the loaded script
});
```

It appends to the document the new, dynamically created, tag `<script src="…">` with given src.

The browser automatically starts loading it and executes when complete. I have a question:

Do I understand it right, that it should work with any kind of links, and get(obtain) functions and their results on that links?

And in this example the second alert should show some sort of result of that functions?

If so, how to insert in src another link with code? I've tried many other links, but second alert didn't work. For example:

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.onload = () => callback(script);
  document.head.append(script);
}
loadScript('https://jsfiddle.net/Rom28/7rL28mso/', script => {
  alert(`Cool, the script ${script.src} is loaded`);
  alert(test()); // function declared in the loaded script
});
```

Please clarify it to me.
Also I want to ask what does `null`  mean in this code:

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;

  script.onload = () => callback(**null**, script);
  script.onerror = () => callback(new Error(`Script load error for ${src}`));

  document.head.append(script);
}
```

It's the same code as above but it also has functionality for handling errors.

Comment: `https://jsfiddle.net/Rom28/7rL28mso/` is not a javascript file. Try attaching an `onerror` handler as well, and take a look at your console.

Answer (score 0):

src parameter should contain link to js file (jsfiddle link doesn't contain js code only so it won't work). For instance you can try to create script.js file with test function in it and put loadScript function in your html file:

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = src;
        script.onload = () => callback(script);
        document.head.append(script);
    }
    loadScript('script.js', script => {
        alert(`Cool, the script ${script.src} is loaded`);
        alert(test()); // function declared in the loaded script
    });
```

So now you have access to the test function which is written in script.js